# NSolve or Reduce for obtaining the results and connecting roots

Tags: equation-solving

Here I have one problem how to solve numerically equation for different values of one parameter x. I used just two digits because of length, but for x=0.57 I should have one real root and for others 0.6, 0.7 ... complex roots. These seven points I want to plot in complex (Re,Im) plane with line. The first problem is that NSolve doesn't work, with Reduce I can obtain some results with problems. Another problem is to understand what's happen when x-> Infinity

```
      x = {0.57, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1};

      NSolve[1/Sqrt[y]
      0.02 (1.`5. I (64.`5. + 2.10 Sqrt[y]) Sqrt[-64.`5. + 
      4.21 Sqrt[y]] + (64.`5. - 2.10 Sqrt[y]) Sqrt[
      64.`5. + 4.21 Sqrt[y]]) Sqrt[-64.`5. + 4.21 Sqrt[y]] Sqrt[
      64.`5. + 4.21 Sqrt[y]] + 0.03 Sqrt[y] - # == 0, y] & /@ x
```

Comment: I've no idea what you mean by "`NSolve` doesn't work". You might find this formulation useful though. `soln[x_] := 
 NSolve[(1/
         Sqrt[y] 0.02 (1.`5. I (64.`5. + 2.10 Sqrt[y]) Sqrt[-64.`5. + 
             4.21 Sqrt[y]] + (64.`5. - 2.10 Sqrt[y]) Sqrt[
            64.`5. + 4.21 Sqrt[y]]) Sqrt[-64.`5. + 4.21 Sqrt[y]] Sqrt[
         64.`5. + 4.21 Sqrt[y]] + 0.03 Sqrt[y] - # == 0), y] &[x]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau `NSolve` tells me that there are no roots, while `Reduce` returns solutions.  I tested on a rationalized version of the system but I didn't verify if the results returned by `Reduce` are correct.

Comment: @Pipe Use `SetPreicision[..., 100]` on your equation and use `WorkingPrecision -> 100` in `NSolve`.  Then it will be able to return the same results `Reduce` gives you.  Sorry, no time for writing this in an answer.  Anyone reading this feel free to post it.

Comment: @Szabolcs Thanks for the clarification. I see where I went astray: I simply missed the first line that defined `x`. The issue I believe is in verification-- without using high precision `NSolve` seems to think the roots it finds are all parasites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per Szabolcs's comment:

```
x = SetPrecision[{0.57, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1, 1.1}, 100];

N@NSolve[SetPrecision[
     1/Sqrt[y] 0.02 (1.`5. I (64.`5. + 2.10 Sqrt[y]) Sqrt[-64.`5. + 
             4.21 Sqrt[y]] + (64.`5. - 2.10 Sqrt[y]) Sqrt[64.`5. +
             4.21 Sqrt[y]]) Sqrt[-64.`5. + 4.21 Sqrt[y]] Sqrt[64.`5. +
             4.21 Sqrt[y]] + 0.03 Sqrt[y] - # == 0,
     100], y, WorkingPrecision -> 100] & /@ x
(*
  {{{y -> 231.101 - 0.0000358251 I}}, {{y -> 231.103 - 0.0000722172 I}},
   {{y -> 231.112 - 0.000351306 I}}, {{y -> 231.127 - 0.000983853 I}},
   {{y -> 231.146 - 0.0021135 I}}, {{y -> 231.171 - 0.00388268 I}},
   {{y -> 231.2 - 0.00643228 I}}}
*)
```

Check:

```
Reduce[
   1/Sqrt[y] 0.02 (1.`5. I (64.`5. + 2.10 Sqrt[y]) Sqrt[-64.`5. + 
           4.21 Sqrt[y]] + (64.`5. - 2.10 Sqrt[y]) Sqrt[64.`5. +
           4.21 Sqrt[y]]) Sqrt[-64.`5. + 4.21 Sqrt[y]] Sqrt[64.`5. +
           4.21 Sqrt[y]] + 0.03 Sqrt[y] - # == 0, y] & /@ N@x
```

> Reduce::ratnz: Reduce was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result. >>
>   ...
>   General::stop: Further output of Reduce::ratnz will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

```
{y == 231.101 - 0.0000358251 I, y == 231.103 - 0.0000722172 I, 
 y == 231.112 - 0.000351306 I, y == 231.127 - 0.000983853 I, 
 y == 231.146 - 0.0021135 I, y == 231.171 - 0.00388268 I, 
 y == 231.2 - 0.00643228 I}
```